# Which memory pages are assiged to files in Linux RAM disk

Tags: linux, ramdisk, tmpfs

I'm trying to locate exact machine memory pages that have been allocated back files which are stored in a Linux RAM disk.  For example, for a process, there is /proc/pid/pagemap that tells you exactly which machine pages a process is using.  I'm looking for similar thing for RAM disks.  Do you know of a kernel module or data structure that may have list of the pages assigned to a RAM disk?

For example, if I create a RAM disk 1MB in size (assuming 4KB pages) that means there should be 256 machine pages assigned to that RAM disk (2^22/2^14=256).

RAM disks build on Linux's page cache, so seems like a good point to start at, but I'm not sure how to correlate which page cache entries correspond to a RAM disk.

Comment: Why do you care? The kernel might move the pages from some RAM to another!

Answer (score 2):

i think its not the exact memory locations that are shown to you in /proc/pid/pagemap.
these are the virtual memory mappings(frame).

pagemap is a new (as of 2.6.25) set of interfaces in the kernel that allow
userspace programs to examine the page tables and related information by
reading files in /proc.

more info follow

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt